# Clean corpus using Quanteda

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

What's the **Quanteda** way of cleaning a corpus like shown in the example below using **tm** (lowercase, remove punct., remove numbers, stem words)? To be clear, I **don't** want to create a document-feature matrix with `dfm()`, I just want a clean corpus that I can use for a specific downstream task.

```
# This is what I want to do in quanteda
library("tm")
data("crude")
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeNumbers)
crude <- tm_map(crude, stemDocument)
```

PS I am aware that I could just do `quanteda_corpus <- quanteda::corpus(crude)`to get what I want, but I would much prefer being able to do everything in Quanteda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is deliberately impossible in `quanteda`.

You can, of course, do the cleaning quite easily without losing the order of words using the `tokens*` set of functions:

```
library("tm")
data("crude")
library("quanteda")
toks <- corpus(crude) %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_wordstem()

print(toks, max_ndoc = 3)
#> Tokens consisting of 20 documents and 15 docvars.
#> reut-00001.xml :
#>  [1] "Diamond"  "Shamrock" "Corp"     "said"     "that"     "effect"  
#>  [7] "today"    "it"       "had"      "cut"      "it"       "contract"
#> [ ... and 78 more ]
#> 
#> reut-00002.xml :
#>  [1] "OPEC"    "may"     "be"      "forc"    "to"      "meet"    "befor"  
#>  [8] "a"       "schedul" "June"    "session" "to"     
#> [ ... and 427 more ]
#> 
#> reut-00004.xml :
#>  [1] "Texaco"   "Canada"   "said"     "it"       "lower"    "the"     
#>  [7] "contract" "price"    "it"       "will"     "pay"      "for"     
#> [ ... and 40 more ]
#> 
#> [ reached max_ndoc ... 17 more documents ]
```

But it is not possible to return this `tokens` object into a corpus. Now it would be possible to write a new function to do this:

```
corpus.tokens <- function(x, ...) {
  quanteda:::build_corpus(
    unlist(lapply(x, paste, collapse = " ")),
    docvars = cbind(quanteda:::make_docvars(length(x), docnames(x)), docvars(x))
  )
}

corp <- corpus(toks)
print(corp, max_ndoc = 3)
#> Corpus consisting of 20 documents and 15 docvars.
#> reut-00001.xml :
#> "Diamond Shamrock Corp said that effect today it had cut it c..."
#> 
#> reut-00002.xml :
#> "OPEC may be forc to meet befor a schedul June session to rea..."
#> 
#> reut-00004.xml :
#> "Texaco Canada said it lower the contract price it will pay f..."
#> 
#> [ reached max_ndoc ... 17 more documents ]
```

But this object, while technically being a `corpus` class object, is not what a corpus is supposed to be. From `?corpus` [emphasis added]:

> **Value**
>
> A corpus class object containing the *original texts*, document-level variables, document-level metadata, corpus-level
> metadata, and default settings for subsequent processing of the
> corpus.

The object above does not meet this description as the original texts have been processed already. Yet the class of the object communicates otherwise. I don't see a reason to break this logic as all subsequent analyses steps should be possible using either `tokens*` or `dfm*` functions.

Comment: This is right: **quanteda** encourages you not to intervene destructively with the original corpus of texts, by removing syntactic elements, word endings, numerals, etc. You can easily do this with _tokens_ objects however and treat that as your "cleaned" text for subsequent work. tokens objects can also be transformed multiple times, although you cannot add back things you have already removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @JBGruber and @KenBenoit. I agree that a corpus should always contain original texts. I need to pre-process my text like above in order to fit word embedding models with packages such as **word2vec** and **text2vec**, which don't require a document-feature matrix or a list of tokens. The corpus.tokens() function works well for concatenating the tokens. Finally, I use `convert(corpus, to = "data.frame")` to get my final pre-processed dataset. Should there be a better way of doing this, please do let me know.

Comment: Have you seen http://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/replication/text2vec.html ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, this vignette is a nice example for fitting GloVe on a quanteda corpus using text2vec (although the title somewhat confusingly mentions word2vec, which is a different package). I needed the pre-processing for use with the word2vec package.